# Provider.render(): A valid React element (or null) returned

Tags: reactjs

I am getting below error in my react app.

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Provider.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
    at invariant (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12594:16)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28633:112)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28164:31)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28060:22)
    at Object.mountComponent
```

Can any one help me on this.

[Issue in react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8euXD.png)

Tried checking the render method.
Tried by removing components one by one to check where went wrong.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Don't add screenshots of code, add relevant code itself. Also you said you tried progressively removing stuff to see what went wrong, what was the outcome of that? You kept going all the way until you were pretty much just returning a single element and still get that error?